# Usercontrol spaces out when added to form

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I designed a user control. When I add it to the form it stretches out and doesn't fit. No idea what is going on here. Any help would be appreciated.

[image: User control]

[image: when added to form]

Comment: There's [Anchor property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.anchor?view=net-5.0), which you should use with every control in your UserControl.

Answer (score 0):

You have not put out more information to be able to help, but well if it is .NET then well your control might be docking in the parent container, you will need to cancel the docking and using anchoring instead.

Comment: It is .net   I actually figured it out. looks like "Autoscale mode: Font" was teh problem. I had designed the usercontrol in 12 font. the main form is in 10 font. so i'm guessing there is some scaling problem. Turned off auto scale mode and i'm in business. thank you

Answer (score 0):

looks like "Autoscale mode: Font" was the problem. I had designed the usercontrol in 12 font. the main form is in 10 font. so I'm guessing there is some scaling problem. Turned off auto scale mode and I'm in business. thank you

Comment: If your problem has been solved, please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).